How can I publish Winform Application with Hunspellx86.dll and Hunspellx64.dll?
I have incorporated a spellcheck feature into my code and it works correctly whenever I debug it within Visual Studio. I am on 4.7.2. However, when I publish the application, the spellcheck does not work because it cannot locate the needed Hunspell.dll file. This error occurs when the Hunspell object is being constructed. I was initially using Nhunspell 1.2.5554.16953 through Nuget.This showed the dll files inside of my solution explorer.
I have also tried NHunspell.Patched and Hunspell.Native and this got rid of the dll files within my solution explorer and it still works within Visual Studio. However, the dll files are not being built when the application is actually created.

Change the "Build Action" property of one of these dlls to "Content", so the Publish feature knows it should publish this dll as well.
